# how to mention div position after div position fixed without margin top or top?

Tags: html, css, position

I have given `#head` `position:fixed;`,

Next, I have given `#wrap` `position:fixed;`

Now, I need content for that need auto alignment I don't want mention margin-top or top.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="head">
  Some absolutely placed item
</div>
<div id="wrap">xxxXxX</div>
<div id="content">Third content</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#head{
  position:fixed;
  left:100px;
  top:100px;
}

#wrap{ 
  position:fixed;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  background-color:#333;
  left:200px;
  top:200px;
}

#content{
  position:relative;
}
```

I need one by one alignment. How can i fix it?

Comment: if you are wanting them to stack underneath each other then don't make them fixed otherwise you will need to set a top, margin top or padding top for the content

Comment: Do you want like this? [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/n6VHy/)

Comment: You can add in the # content display:block; text-align:center; this will align the contents of the block in the middle

Comment: @Pete I need excatly like this only.

Comment: @Mr_Green thanks. but  if i scroll #content i need overlap that #wrap. #header and #content will touch.

Comment: @marvan then you will need to use js to set the initial top value as there is no way in css to make the content be place relatively to fixed elements - [fixed elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) are removed from the current page's flow and positioned relative to the viewport

Answer (score 0):

If you are not ok with the alignment fix in `content` div, you should probably use the alignment values in `body` or `body specified id`, like

```
body {  
margin:20px 0;  
}
```

or

```
#bodyID {  
margin:20px 0;  
}
```

Here `<body id="bodyId">.....</body>`

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to change the html structure like this

```
<div id="head">
  Some absolutely placed item
</div>
<div id="wrap">xxxXxX
<div id="content">Third content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but Not like this. if i scroll #content i need overlap that #wrap. #header and #content will touch.